# Mapping java.long to oracle.Number(14)

Tags: java, oracle, mapping, sqldatatypes

I have db column whose datatype is Number (15) and i have the corresponding field in java classes as *long*. The question is how would i map it using *java.sql.Types*.

- would Types.BIGINT work?
- Or shall i use something else?

P.S:
I can't afford to change the datatype within java class and within DB.

Comment: If you cannot change neither the database not the code - what is the purpose of the question?

Comment: I think OP meant they can't afford to change both and was wondering which one should be changed. I could be wrong though

Answer (score 12):

From [this link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/basic.htm#1021193)  it says that `java.sql.Types.BIGINT` should be used for `long` in Java to `Number` in SQL (Oracle).

Attaching screenshot of the table in case the link ever dies.

[image: SQL and JDBC datatypes]

Comment: Note: `Integer` ***vs*** `int` and ***nullables***

Answer (score 5):

A good place to find reliable size mappings between Java and Oracle Types is in the Hibernate ORM tool.  Documented [in the code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.hibernate/com.springsource.org.hibernate/3.3.1/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle8iDialect.java#78), Hibernate uses an Oracle NUMBER(19,0) to represent a java.sql.Types.BIGINT which should map to a long primitave

Answer (score 0):

I always use wrapper type, because wrapper types can be express null values.

In this case I will use Long wrapper type.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more? are you referring to something in Types.?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I couldn't modify the Java Type or the Database Type. In my situation I needed to execute a native SQL query (to be able to utilize Oracle's Recursive query abilities) and map the result set to a non-managed entity (essentially a simple pojo class).

I found a combination of [addScalar](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html#addScalar%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%29) and [setResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setResultTransformer%28org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer%29) worked wonders.

```
hibernateSes.createSQLQuery("SELECT \n"
        + " c.notify_state_id as \"notifyStateId\", \n"
        + " c.parent_id as \"parentId\",\n"
        + " c.source_table as \"sourceTbl\", \n"
        + " c.source_id as \"sourceId\", \n"
        + " c.msg_type as \"msgType\", \n"
        + " c.last_updt_dtm as \"lastUpdatedDateAndTime\"\n"
        + " FROM my_state c\n"
        + "LEFT JOIN my_state p ON p.notify_state_id = c.parent_id\n"
        + "START WITH c.notify_state_id = :stateId\n"
        + "CONNECT BY PRIOR c.notify_state_id = c.parent_id")
    .addScalar("notifyStateId", Hibernate.LONG)
    .addScalar("parentId", Hibernate.LONG)
    .addScalar("sourceTbl",Hibernate.STRING)
    .addScalar("sourceId",Hibernate.STRING)
    .addScalar("msgType",Hibernate.STRING)
    .addScalar("lastUpdatedDateAndTime", Hibernate.DATE)
    .setParameter("stateId", notifyStateId)
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyState.class))
    .list();
```

Where `notifyStateId`, `parentId`, `sourceTbl`, `sourceId`, `msgType`, and `lastUpdatedDateAndTime` are all properties of `MyState`.

Without the `addScalar`'s, I would get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch` because Hibernate was turning Oracle's `Number` type into a `BigDecimal` but `notifyStateId` and `parentId` are `Long` types on `MyState`.